# ruby subclass filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey! Maybe I am getting the idea of a subclass wrong, but I have a Person model and it has an attrib called "age" so

```
Person.first.age #=> '20'
```

Now I want to have a model that's basically persons 55 or older so I know I can have a class like this: 
class Senior < Person
end

But how can I "pre-filter" the Senior class so that every object belonging to that class has age >= 55?

```
Senior.first.age #=> 56
```

UPDATE1:
So say I have Company has_many people, and Person belongs_to Company, so
Company.first.people #=> ["Jack", "Kate"]

If Jack's age is > 55, will it work then:
Company.first.seniors #=> "jack"

Or

Company.first.people.senior(s) #=> "jack"?

I know that named_scope might be what I want, but I also notice that named_scope seems to be a method on the Class variable Person. Not its instances, which does make sense to me. -- So if I were to devise such a convenience filter for a collection of activerecord models (objects of the same class), how do I go about it? I am guessing I'd have to use a "detect" for such an array, but where will this go inside the Model's definition?

Update 2
I am quite sure I haven't been clear, so example
Want: first company's 55 or older people
Company.first.people.detect{|p| p.age > 54}

I know this isn't very long, but my conditions will go farther than just > 54 and it becomes clumsy to do this detect each time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use named scopes

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :seniors, :conditions => ['age >= ?', 55]
end

Person.seniors.first.age #=> 83
```

Comment: I would totally recommend to use this approach.

Comment: I guess I forgot another use that I do want in having a subclass senior, it is added as an update to the original queston. Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: so you can use  default_scope in Senior < Person class and Person abstraction as Marcel offered

Comment: to fl00r's comment: with Marcel J.'s method, even though I have never explicitly defined Company has_many seniors, Senior belongs_to Company, I can still do Company.first.seniors?

Comment: Use fl00rs approach and define `def seniors; people.seniors; end` in Company. This will behave exactly like a `has_many :seniors`, but will be much better design.

Comment: Got it! Thanks fl00r, Marcel, and Salil.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick.

```
class Person
  def self.abstract_class?
    true
  end
end

class Junior < Person
  set_table_name "people"
  default_scope :conditions => "people.age < 55"
end

class Senior < Person
  set_table_name "people"
  default_scope :conditions => "people.age >= 55"
end
```

But I would reconsider whether this is a good idea. But if you decide to go for it, please use an abstract "Person" class, to avoid problems with Rails' STI implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it using Subclass but You can do it using class method as following.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.senior
    find(:all, :conditions=>["age>=?"], 55)
  end
end
```

and you can call it from the any controller as follows

```
senior_age = Person.senior.first.age unless Person.senior.blank?
```